# Map XML list / XML elements with different attribute values to separate fields

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

I have an XML file that looks like this:

**XML file:**

```xml
<foobar name="quux">
    <supplement key="head">this is a text row</supplement>
    <supplement key="body">this is some other text row</supplement>
</foobar>
```

I would like to have `<supplement>` mapped to two separate variables; `head` and `body`.

**Java POJO:**

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "foobar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foobar {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    private String head;  // should be mapped to XMLs supplement:key=head

    private String body;  // should be mapped to XMLs supplement:key=body
}
```

Can this be done? If so how?

Another doable solution would be to have both `<supplement>`-tags added to a `HashMap<String, String>`, where the `key`-value is used as index, but I have failed to do this unfortunately.

As a workaround I have a solution to map `<supplement>` as a list, using:

```java
@XmlElement(name = "supplement")
private List<NewSupplement> supplements = new ArrayList<>();
```

The problem with this solution is that list index value is decided by the order of `<supplement>`-tags in the XML file, ie. if `key="head"` comes first in the XML file this is added to index 0 but if `key="body"` comes first that is added to index 0, which might cause me some problems / unnecessary headache.

I would rather have the first solution (or a HashMap) if that is doable.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue myself after some more hours, with the help of `@XmlPath` from  [EclipseLink MOXy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy). I mapped the `<supplement>`-tags to two individual variables.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "foobar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foobar {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlPath("supplement[@key='head']/text()")
    private String head;  // maps to XMLs supplement:key=head

    @XmlPath("supplement[@key='body']/text()")
    private String body;  // maps to XMLs supplement:key=body
}
```

EclipseLink MOXy, maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```